# How to detect if a nullable field is missing from BizTalk orchestration input?

Tags: c#, xml, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I have set-up a BizTalk 2010 Orchestration which receives a XML which contains a number of fields (this orchestration is exposed as a web service). Some fields are int and nullable so the caller can provide nothing for them.

In this case, when my orchestration's "Message Assignment" tries to read those fields and assign their value to another message, everything breaks down and the instance is suspended.
(All input fields are distinguished so I can use them in message assignment).

The question is: How can I detect that a field's value is present in the input of orchestration?

(BTW using a default value for the field did not solve the problem)

Answer (score 2):

What you describe, "read those fields and assign their value to an other message", is typically handled with a Map.

If you have non-message source values, you can assign a temp value in the Map, then set it by either a Distinguished Filed or the xpath function.

Comment: But I cannot use "Map" and transform because my messages do not appear under "Source" and "Destination" list in message transform configuration.

Comment: Then that's part of the problem.  Are they XmlDocument type?  You have to use a Schema based type as a Map Source and Destination.

Comment: They are input/output of web-services that will be called during orchestration. I have designed those web-services in .NET asmx format without any special coding but in the BT project, I cannot select those messages for a transform. I think it is related to "Multi-Part" messages but finally I gave up the issue.